# Implementing infinite scroll with MUI DataGridPro scrolls the list unexpectedly on fetching more items

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, infinite-scroll, mui-x-data-grid

I am using DataGridPro and have implemented infinite scroll using the `onRowsScrollEnd` property.

I have certain items that are pinned items in the list which are displayed as collapsable rows (treeData) through `path` property. The pinned items are fetched separately (only once when the page loads) and stored in a state variable `pinnedItems`.

The other items are fetched initially and updated through the fetchMore function as the user scrolls. It is stored in the `otherItems` state variable.

I have another state variable `allItems` which contains all the pinned Items and other items and is updated when `pinnedItems.length` or `otherItems.length` changes through useEffect. `allItems` is passed to the `rows` variable in DataGridPro.

****The Problem: ****

1. When the pinned items is less than 46 and the pinned items row is expanded, the infinite scroll works fine i.e. the scroll position stays where it was last when trying to fetch more, and other items get added to the bottom (as expected)

**BUT**

2. when the pinned items number is greater than 45 and pinned items row is expanded, the scrollbar moves up to a random location to fetch more items.
3. If the pinned items row is not expanded, the scrollbar stays in it last position and works as expected.

I am having a hard time figuring out what the problem could be. Please help. Thank you in advance.

code:

```
  const [
    listOtherItems,
    {
      loading,
      data: {
        listOtherItems: { data: otherItemsList, pagination: pagination } = {},
      } = {},
      fetchMore,
    },
  ] = useLazyQuery(LIST_OTHER_ITEMS);


const [
    listPinnedItems,
    {
      loading: pinnedItemsLoading,
      data: {
        listPinnedItems: {
          data: pinnedItemsList,
          pagination: pinTicketPagination,
        } = {},
      } = {},
    },
  ] = useLazyQuery(LIST_PINNED_ITEMS);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (pinnedItemsList?.length) {
      const rows = [];
      for (let t of pinnedItemsList) {
        const row = getModifiedItem(t);
        rows.push(row);
      }
      const formattedItems = formatItems(rows);
      setPinnedItems(formattedItems);
      return;
    }
    setPinnedItems([]);
  }, [pinnedItemsList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAllItems([...pinnedItems, ...otherItems);
  }, [pinnedItems, otherItems]);



const handleScroll = async (params) => {
    const hasMoreData =
      allItems.length > 0 && allItems.length < pagination?.totalSize;
    if (hasMoreData) {
      setPaginationModel({
        page: paginationModel?.page + 1,
        pageSize: paginationModel?.pageSize,
      });

      await fetchMore({
        variables: {
          ...variables,
          pagination: {
            page: paginationModel?.page + 1,
            pageSize: paginationModel?.pageSize,
          },
        },
        updateQuery: (
          prev,
          {
            fetchMoreResult: {
              listOtherItems: { data: data },
            },
          },
        ) => {
          if (data?.length) {
            const modifiedData = data.map((item) =>
              getModifiedItem(item),
            );
            setAllItems(allItems.concat(modifiedData));
          }
        },
      });
    }
  };


  return (
    <DataGridPro
            apiRef={apiRef}
            columns={columns}
            disableColumnPinning
            disableColumnResize={true}
            disableMultipleColumnsFiltering
            disableMultipleColumnsSorting
            disableVirtualization
            disableSelectionOnClickap
            disableColumnFilter
            disableDensitySelector
            disableColumnSelector
            disableColumnMenu
            getTreeDataPath={(row) => row.path}
            groupingColDef={groupingColDef}
            getRowClassName={getRowClassName}
            hideFooter={true}
            hideFooterPagination={true}
            hideFooterRowCount={true}
            loading={loading || loadingMore}
            onRowClick={handleRowClick}
            onRowEnter={handleRowClick}
            onRowOver={handleRowClick}
            onRowLeave={handleRowLeave}
            onRowsScrollEnd={handleScroll}
            onSortModelChange={(model) => {
              if (model?.length) {
                setSort({
                  sortKey: model[0].field,
                  sortOrder: model[0].sort.toUpperCase(),
                });
              }
            }}
            page={paginationModel.page}
            paginationMode="server"
            paginationModel={paginationModel}
            pageSize={paginationModel.pageSize}
            resizable={false}
            rowCount={pagination?.totalSize ?? 0}
            rowHeight={48}
            rows={allItems}
            scrollEndThreshold={paginationModel.pageSize}
            sortingMode="server"
            sortingOrder={['desc', 'asc']}
            }}
            treeData
          />
)
```

1. I tried setting the items in a ref to prevent re-rendering but did not help. Also, one thing to note is if the number of pinned items is less than 45, it works fine in the same circumstances.